# C# TCP/IP Socket Client has to connect to more than 30+ socket server, and receive 258 bytes from each server at 8ms cycle

Tags: c#, sockets, concurrency, client

I have been confronted with the problem. The following is description:

1.There are more than 30 devices that implemented as raw TCP/IP socket server at their port A, and there could been only one client to connect them. Each server will send 258-byte data cyclically at 8 milliseconds.

2.During the cyclical data transmission, the client has to make sure each server is working fine by querying servers through their port B. The querying will take place about 5 times during 8ms on each server.

3.What's more, client will storage all received data in 0.5 second.

4.With i5 CPU/2.3Ghz, client can only bear 5 to 7 servers.

My question is that are there any opensource projects or some advances that can help to improve the bearing capacity？

Comment: That's roughly 1 million bytes a second - broadly possible, as long as latency isn't the problem. I suspect this really comes down to the code your using. What did your i5 experiment use? A single thread looping over the connections? Thread per connection? Async IO? Or...?

Comment: I used single thread for each server connection, didn't use asynchronous file I/O.

Comment: I would have *expected* that to be tolerable in this scenario. Are you sure the real problem isn't just bad code? We can't really comment on that. Context: I have TCP servers that scale to 20k+ connections, although they aren't running on the tight loop you describe

Comment: For those servers, their port A is used to transmit data every 8ms (must be guaranteed of no data lost), and port B is used to receive more than 5 queries form the same client in every 0.5s. So for each server, I had used one thread for port A and one(0.5s timer thread) for port B. During the 0.5s, data from a server must be stored into the client , server queried status must be returned (Latency may take place here).